# Enable the multiple checkbox using Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have multiple checkboxes. I need to enable the checkbox at a time using Id. The is working fine while using the following code

```
$('#canReadFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
$('#canShareFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
$('#canUpdateFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
$('#canCreateFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
$('#canDeleteFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
```

But while using the following code it is not working

```
$('#canReadFlag'+index,'#canShareFlag'+index,'#canUpdateFlag'+index,'#canDeleteFlag'+index,'#canCreateFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
```

In order to enable the checkbox at a time, what should I do using Id

Comment: create a class with `index` appended in checkbox, then use that class for check/uncheck

Comment: I have updated answer probably as with your requirement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried to toggle the checkbox also,

So once any checkbox is checked all other are **checked** and

it will **unchecked** when you clicked on the checked checkbox.

It may also **disable** the checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(e) {
    var index = 1;
    var status = true;
    $('#canReadFlag' + index + ',#canShareFlag' + index + ',#canUpdateFlag' + index + ',#canDeleteFlag' + index + ',#canCreateFlag' + index).prop('checked', status);

    $('#canReadFlag' + index + ',#canShareFlag' + index + ',#canUpdateFlag' + index + ',#canDeleteFlag' + index + ',#canCreateFlag' + index).prop('disabled', status);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="canReadFlag1" name="canReadFlag1" value="1">Can read
<input type="checkbox" id="canShareFlag1" name="canShareFlag1" value="1">Can share
<input type="checkbox" id="canUpdateFlag1" name="canUpdateFlag1" value="1">Can update
<input type="checkbox" id="canDeleteFlag1" name="canDeleteFlag1" value="1">Can delete
<input type="checkbox" id="canCreateFlag1" name="canCreateFlag1" value="1">Can create
```

Hope code will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is working fine according to my requirement

Comment: `id` attributes are meant to be unique in your DOM... please consider editing your answer

Comment: @ochi I respect your comment and your suggestion but that is why I added the index as the variable that will be considered as dynamic value. hope you may take in your consideration.

Comment: Not to the HTML, you didn't. The moment you check one box, all of them are checked

Comment: @Ochi I tried to show him toggle logic even he did not specify And I don't think so it was wrong but by the way I have updated an answer due to an objection.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that, IDs are meant to be unique in a DOM. Your code breaks this rule and this will create problems down the road (with other JS and DOM manipulation like this) - btw your code does not toggle anything at the moment.  But, hey, my suggestion is for you to improve your answer.  It's up to you if you wish to do so.

Comment: @ochi please I really appreciate your suggestion. can you tell me at which please you may find my code break the rule? I will learn something from then it's good to me also.

Comment: I tried showing this with working example only that means.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the comma into the string

```
$('#canReadFlag'+index+',#canShareFlag'+index+',#canUpdateFlag'+index+',#canDeleteFlag'+index+',#canCreateFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now it is working for .prop('checked', true), but it is not working for .prop('disabled', true).

Comment: `disabled` uses `disabled` (instead of `true`) as the property value (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to assign a `class` to all the similar type of checkbox in which you want to get it `checked` and use that `class` to set the checkbox `checked`.

```js
var index = 1;
//use the class selector
$('.cbFlag'+index).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='canReadFlag1' class='cbFlag1' type='checkbox' />canReadFlag <br>
<input id='canShareFlag1' class='cbFlag1' type='checkbox' />canShareFlag <br>
<input id='canUpdateFlag1' class='cbFlag1' type='checkbox' />canUpdateFlag <br>
<input id='canCreateFlag1' class='cbFlag1' type='checkbox' />canCreateFlag <br>
<input id='canDeleteFlag1' class='cbFlag1' type='checkbox' />canDeleteFlag
```

Comment: In my case, I am iterating the script using index value using the same code

Answer (score 0):

Usually checkbox are for multiple selection instead you can use radio button if you want one option at a time by giving same name, in case of checkbox you can do one thing first take all the checkboxes in variable by documents.getElementByTagName and then first uncheck all then check that one checkbox by e.target.
Second thing you can do it by assigning checked property true and false. In that case on click of any checkbox set property false of all checkboxes except clicked one.